# Where host the backend when NextJS is hosted on Vercel?

Tags: hosting, backend, next.js

I'm creating a website with NextJS and will deploy it with Vercel.
NextJS has API routes that Vercel will deploy to AWS Lambda if I understand correctly.

As backend I will use mysql like here: https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-next-and-mysql-with-vercel

But what is the best place to host this?
Is AWS the fastest because AWS Lambda is used?
But what region should I use then?
Wat is the best way to make it fast in eu and us?

Comment: [Qovery](https://www.qovery.com) is a decent product with a Vercel-like experience on top of your AWS account. It's open-source with a cloud version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the region with this code in a API:

```
export default (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION || "NOT SET" });
};
```

The result was `us-west-1` for me. (I live in Europe)

I found information about this here:
https://vercel.com/knowledge/choosing-deployment-regions

This seems to be correct for a hobby account.
For Pro you can select a region, but only one.
You need enterprise for multiple region.

The best place to host mysql would be in the aws us-west-1 region but I decided to not use Vercel because I prefer a different solution.

This may be an alternative: https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js